How can I create reusable composable methods to be used in the middle of jooq queries?
How i can reused/compose part of a JOOQ query in a repository method? has a good answer for multiple queries that start the same way with different later components.
What if, instead, I want to reuse some logic that appears in the middle of multiple queries, or at the end? Below is an example where I'm limiting the number of rows joined from a table:
select(TABLE1.FOO, TABLE2.BAR)
.from(TABLE1)
// I want to reuse the code from HERE
.leftJoin(TABLE2)
.on(TABLE2.FOREIGN_ID.eq(TABLE1.ID))
.and(
    TABLE2.ID.eq(
        ctx.select(TABLE2.ID)
            .from(TABLE2)
            .where(TABLE2.FOREIGN_ID.eq(TABLE1.ID))
            .limit(1)))
// to HERE
.join(TABLE3)
.on(ETC)

That middle block of code is going to look very similar every time I use it. The parts that change are TABLE2, TABLE2.ID, and TABLE2.FOREIGN_ID.eq(TABLE1.ID). TABLE2.ID might be implicit if TABLE2 has a unique key. TABLE2.FOREIGN_ID.eq(TABLE1.ID) might be implicit if FOREIGN_ID is a foreign key and TABLE1 is within scope to access.
Is there a way to do this that I can chain with existing jooq methods?
select(TABLE1.FOO, TABLE2.BAR)
.from(TABLE1)
.MyUniqueJoinMethod(TABLE2, TABLE2.ID, TABLE2.FOREIGN_ID.eq(TABLE1.ID))
.join(TABLE3)
.on(ETC)

Or will I have to build it as a standalone function that wraps the first half of the query in a more ugly fashion?
MyUniqueJoinFunction(TABLE2, TABLE2.ID, TABLE2.FOREIGN_ID.eq(TABLE1.ID),
  select(TABLE1.FOO, TABLE2.BAR)
  .from(TABLE1)
).join(TABLE3)
.on(ETC)

To be clear, this particular join-with-limit functionality is not the only place I want to apply an answer to this question. I want to be able to break arbitrary query components out into a function/method, in the same way that the answer to the older linked question allows for leading query components.

Just a little aside, what is your reusable join supposed to do? It looks very wrong, although i might be parsing the jooq-query wrong

@siggemannen it limits the right side of the join to one row per row on the left side

yeah, but without sort, it's pointless

See numerous online discussions of GROUP BY without using aggregate functions for elaboration on why it's not pointless

Ok, good luck with your code!

Key to understanding dynamic SQL with jOOQ is to think of every expression as dynamic, not just the SELECT query method chains. When you have dynamic joins, think of it this way:
ctx.select()
   .from(table)
   .where(conditions)
   .fetch();

And now, both your Table and Condition objects are constructed dynamically, e.g. as follows:
// The parts that you always have
Table<?> table = TABLE1;
Condition conditions = ...;

// The parts that are added dynamically:
if (something) {
    table = table.join(TABLE2).on(TABLE2.FOREIGN_ID.eq(TABLE1.ID))
    conditions = conditions.and(...);
}

Obviously, local variables and the imperative style above are just one way to approach this. You can use more functional approaches as well. There's not really a right or wrong answer to your specific question here, but there's a key message that every jOOQ query is dynamic, and every Table, Field, Condition, etc. is passed to your query dynamically, whether you think of it this way or not.

I'm providing example using a Kotlin, but i think you easily can do it in Java too
For generics repo we're doing like that:
abstract class AbstractRepository<T : Table<R>, R : UpdatableRecord<*>>(
    protected val table: T,
    private val baseCondition: Condition = DSL.noCondition(),
) {

    @Autowired
    protected lateinit var dsl: DSLContext

    fun newRec(): R {
        return dsl.newRecord(table)
    }

    fun insertOnConflictDoNothing(record: R): Int {
        return dsl.insertInto(table).set(record).onConflictDoNothing().execute()
    }

    fun store(vararg records: R) {
        dsl.batchStore(*records).execute()
    }

    fun store(records: Collection<R>) {
        dsl.batchStore(records).execute()
    }

    fun deleteBy(vararg where: (T) -> Condition): Int {
        return dsl.deleteFrom(table).where(foldConditions(where)).execute()
    }

    fun getOneBy(where: (T) -> Condition): R? {
        return dsl.selectFrom(table).where(baseCondition.and(where.invoke(table))).fetchOne()
    }

    fun getAllBy(where: (T) -> Condition): R? {
        return dsl.selectFrom(table).where(baseCondition.and(where.invoke(table))).fetchOne()
    }

    protected fun foldConditions(where: Array<out (T) -> Condition>) =
        where.fold(DSL.noCondition()) { acc, func -> acc.and(func(table)) }
}

